# Error with Switch class after TFS checkout

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an old VB.NET that I am asked to debug. It is under TFS (perhaps 2012). When I download it to my PC and change nothing it compiles successfully. But as soon as I check it out, I get
`BC30109: 'Switch' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression.`

This is the code

```
Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = ExecuteReader()
Do While rdr.Read
   If Not IsDBNull(rdr("VAR_VALUE")) Then
       DefaultSalUnit = Switch(CLng(rdr("VAR_VALUE")) = 12, "Monthly", CLng(rdr("VAR_VALUE")) = 1, "Yearly")
   End If
Loop
rdr.Close()
```

DefaultSalUnit is a *String*.
I tried imporing `System.Diagnostics` and it disappears instantly. Appending it to `Switch` still generates the same error.

Why is this weird behavior? Ideas?

Comment: I think you're looking for `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction` switch.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer Please post it so I can upvote and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is a clash between namespaces.

You're getting System.Diagnostics and you should be looking for Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.

You can either prefix your method call or juggle with the namespaces to force the correct selection.